# PL/SQL: ORA-06550: group function not allowed here

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by, having-clause

I'm having the following errors

[image]

with this code

```
DECLARE v_manager_id NUMERIC;
BEGIN
SELECT MANAGER_ID INTO v_manager_id, COUNT(MANAGER_ID)
FROM DEPARTMENTS
GROUP BY MANAGER_ID
HAVING COUNT(MANAGER_ID) > 1;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
DECLARE 
  v_manager_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MANAGER_ID 
  INTO v_manager_id
  FROM DEPARTMENTS
  GROUP BY MANAGER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(MANAGER_ID) > 1;
END;
```

Alternatively, if you need value of `count(manager_id)`, you'd have to declare a variable, such as

```
DECLARE 
  v_manager_id NUMBER;
  v_count      NUMBER
BEGIN
  SELECT MANAGER_ID, COUNT(MANAGER_ID)
  INTO v_manager_id, v_count
  FROM DEPARTMENTS
  GROUP BY MANAGER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(MANAGER_ID) > 1;
END;
```

Comment: Both queries will throw TOO_MANY_ROWS unless there's only one Manager who manages two departments.

Comment: Most probably, yes, @APC. I don't know what this query will be used for, there's no *environment* to put it in.